# preg_replace replace symbols inside captured group

Tags: php, regex

I'm a little stumped, I need to wrap some characters inside quotes, but I need to replace commas to dots *inside* the replaced text. Is there a single command for that?

Currently, I am doing this:

```
preg_replace( '[\b([0-9\.,]{16,})]', '="\1"', $chunk );
```

which surrounds numeric strings longer than 15 symbols with `="` and `"`, but I need to zap any existing dots into commas (Excel compatibility, don't ask).

I am aware there are two-step solutions, but I have a feeling I don't know some PHP/REGEX feature to do it faster/better.

---

**EDIT:** The most performant answer wins, as I'll be dealing with arbitrary size CSV files, which can grow into gigabytes (even though I/O might be the bottleneck here).

Comment: `preg_replace_callback`.

Comment: You can pass arrays as both the first and second parameter of `preg_replace`. So your current parameters would be the first item in their respective arrays, and then you add an item in each array for the dots-to-comma replacement.

Comment: guys, thanks, why aren't these answers?

Comment: I wasn't saying anything that couldn't be found in the [manual for preg_replace()](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), so it didn't really feel right making it an answer. Plus I was trying to put together a working example, but I'm not able to get your posted code to work the way you said it does.

Comment: Thanks, I adjusted the code according to @Sam's suggestions, the snippet is now what I currently use in production, without the last minute fix. Anyway, the array would not suffice as it's a two-step solution and it would need to search for numericals twice - once to replace commas, and then to wrap them, which raises the complexity twicefold...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`preg_replace_callback()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) lets you create a callback function with an array of your match groups; the value you return is what replaces the match.  We can use `str_replace()` to replace all existing dots into commas for the second capture group before adding the `="` and `"`.

```
preg_replace_callback(
    '[(\b)([0-9\.,]{16,})]',
    function($matches) {
        $value = str_replace('.', ',', $matches[2]);
        return $matches[1] . '="' . $value . '"';
    },
    $chunk
);
```

Two notes..first, I would use one of the ["standard" delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) (`/`, `~`, `#`).  And second, `\b` just matches the position as a word boundary..it doesn't actually capture any data.  So you can replace the capture groups to make it more readable.  Final expression:

```
preg_replace_callback(
    '/\b[0-9\.,]{16,}/',
    function($matches) {
        $value = str_replace('.', ',', $matches[0]);
        return '="' . $value . '"';
    },
    $chunk
);
```

Comment: thanks for the second note, I just replaced that part, thinking it was a bug and surprised it seemed to work up until now

Comment: If you are looking for performance, there is a chance (depending on your CSV file) you can use [`fopen()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and [`fgets()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) to read the file line by line..which would greatly reduce your memory footprint.

Comment: Yeah, I am doing something along those lines, although the csv source is not a file, but that's irrelevant, anyway, I'm going with your solution, thanks a lot!

Comment: as for regex delimiters, I find the square brackets much more readable when the regex itself does not contain them, which in this case, it does, so yeah, I'm changing it.

Comment: Fair enough, its just atypical so I thought I'd bring it up.  Thanks for the accept :)